# Custom MSBuild Task emit a warning

Tags: c#, msbuild

How do I make a custom build task emit a warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task, that you have to dervive from, has a member:

```
public Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper Log { get; }
```

To make your task emit a message use this. Specifically:

```
public void LogWarning(string message, params object[] messageArgs)
    Member of Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper
```

For example:

```
Log.LogWarning("My Warning");
```